# Extjs 4 set combox values in form load event

Tags: combobox, extjs4, store

I have a form containing 2 comobox fields, which are linked combox fields.

Chapters and lessons

When a user selects a chapter, list of lessons in that chapter will be shown.

How to filter the lessons combo based on chapters combo in EXTjs 4. If chapters combo is selected then only lessons combo should show lessons, otherwise it should be empty.

And how to set the cmobo values selected when form data is loaded from server and populated in form fields.

Chapters store

```
var chapter_store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['chapter_id', 'chapter_name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: BASE_URL + 'courses/chapters/getChaptersCombo/' + course_id,
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },
    storeId: 'chapter_id'
});
```

Lessons store

```
var lesson_store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['lesson_id',
             //'chapter_name',
             'lesson_name', 'lc_relation_id'
             ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: BASE_URL + 'courses/lessons/getLessonsCombo/' + course_id,
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },
    storeId: 'lesson_id'
});
```

Form with linked combos

```
 var quiz_form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        //readOnly:true,
        id: 'test_chapter_combo',
        name: 'test_chapter_combo',
        //hiddenName: 'test_linkchapter_val',
        displayField: 'chapter_name',
        valueField: 'chapter_id',
        fieldLabel: 'Select Chapter',
        allowBlank: false,
        blankText: 'Chapter is required',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        queryMode: 'remote',
        store: chapter_store,
        selectOnFocus: true,
        listeners: {
            select: {
                fn: function (combo, value) {
                    var comboLesson = Ext.getCmp('test_lesson_combo');
                    comboLesson.clearValue();
                    lesson_store.load({
                        params: {
                            chapters_id: combo.getValue()
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        //readOnly:true,
        id: 'test_lesson_combo',
        name: 'test_lesson_combo',
        //hiddenName: 'test_linklesson_val',
        displayField: 'lesson_name',
        valueField: 'lc_relation_id',
        mode: 'local',
        fieldLabel: 'Link To Lesson',
        allowBlank: false,
        blankText: 'Lesson is required',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        store: edu_lesson_store,
        queryMode: 'remote'
    }]
});
```

Loading form data from server

```
quiz_form.getForm().load({
    url: BASE_URL + 'courses/getCourseTest/' + quiz_id,
    method: 'POST'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dunno which server side technology are you using, but i'm sure you can get some inspiration/guidance following these 2 great links:

- [Extjs Cascading (Dependent) Combo Boxes](http://www.foscode.com/extjs-cascading-dependent-combo-boxes/)
- [ExtJs 4 cascading ComboBox example using Java Servlet and MySQL](http://as400samplecode.blogspot.com/2012/01/extjs-cascading-combobox-java-servlet-2.html)

HTH!

Comment: I'm using PHP - codeigniter as server side technology. Now filtering works fine. How to set the values in combobox when i'm loading form data from server (say edit mode for already saved form ) and using a remote store. If a use a array data store for combox, values are automatically selected in to combox when loading form data from server.

Comment: Try to set the name property in the combo config to "chapter_id", then use try to use form.loadRecord(model_record), form will bind the values from your model record to the form fields which have name="model_field_name", more info on loadRecord() here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord